# In Sitecore CDP and Personalize, Is it possible to get the guest ref using the Browser Id?

Tags: personalization, cdp, sitecore-personalize

I have the browser id of the guest in `Sitecore CDP` and `Personalize`, but I want to update the guest using the `REST APIs`. To update the guest using the `REST APIs` I require the guest ref. Is there a way to get the guess ref using the browser id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the guest ref using the id you can:

**Use the JavaScript Library**

```
Boxever.browserShow(Boxever.browser_id,Boxever.client_key,function(data){
    console.log(data.customer.ref);
  }, 'json');
```

or

**Use the REST Locate endpoint**

You can use the Guest REST API to perform the locate guests function to return guests using their email address or other identifying information. After you perform the  locate guests function, you can use the guestRef included in the response to retrieve the full guest record.

```
$ curl -H "Accept: application/json" \
        "https://{apiEndpoint}/v2/guests?email=jack.smith@boxever.com"
```

REST Locate Endpoint :
https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-1/use-the-locate-guests-function-in-sitecore-cdp-rest-api.html
or

**Use a Full Stack Interactive Experience**

Create a Full Stack Interactive Experience that given the Browser Id returns the guest ref.

Full Stack Interactive experiences are available as part of `Sitecore Personalize`. Therefore for organizations with Sitecore CDP only, this solution is not available.

Full Stack Interactive Experiences Endpoint : https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/sitecore-customer-data-platform--data-model-2-1/sitecore-cdp-flow-execution-data-model-rest-api.html

Full Stack Interactive Experiences Overview: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/users/sitecore-personalize/composing-the-api-response-for-an-interactive-experiment.html

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method is to use the browser ID via the Rest APIs:

`https://{{apiEndpoint}}/v2/guestContexts?browserRef={{browserid}}`

This API isn't listed publicly: https://doc.sitecore.com/cdp/en/developers/api/rest-apis.html

However, I simply viewed the network traffic while I searched for "bid:{my-id}" in the search view and I saw it was used. It seems to work just fine.